# FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, react-native

I am trying to get started with integrating Facebook login into an ios app. I have followed the instructions at developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started and am having trouble running the application.

1. Created a Frameworks group in Xcode
2. Opened ~/Documents/FacebookSDK using Finder
3. Dragged the FBSDKCoreKit.framework, FBSDKLoginKit.framework, and FBSDKShareKit.framework files into the Frameworks group of Xcode's Project Navigator and chose to create groups for added folders and unchecked copy items if needed for destination
   [Frameworks Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puOUO.png)
4. Added ~/Documents/FacebookSDK to the project's Framework Search Paths setting in the Build Settings Tab of my project
   [Framework Search Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaPnV.png)
5. Configured the project's Info.plist file with the link's recommendations.

From terminal, when I do sudo react-native run-ios I get 2 errors:

1. /Users/user/projectFolder/projectName/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios/RCTFBSDK/share/RCTFBSDKShareDialog.h:21:9: fatal error: 
     'FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h' file not found

`#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>`

2. /Users/user/projectFolder/projectName/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios/RCTFBSDK/core/RCTFBSDKAppEvents.h:21:9: fatal error: 
     'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found

`#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>`

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I resolved it by moving the Framework files in my `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` so XCode noticed they were missing. I then relinked them, ran `Clean` and then `Build`. Hope this helps.